# Guzzle POST XML

Tags: php, xml, guzzle

I am having a problem. I'm trying to post some form data to a CRM and their documentation states that it has to be done using XML

```
A create request may look like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
 <lead>
 <key>[KEY]</key>
 <leadgroup>10</leadgroup>
 <site>20</site>
 <introducer>30</introducer>
 <reference>Lead123</reference>
 <source>Google</source>
 <medium>PPC</medium>
 <term>Loans</term>
 <cost>10.00</cost>
 <value>100.00</value>
 <title>Mr</title>
 <firstname>John</firstname>
 <lastname>Smith</lastname>
 <company>ABC Ltd.</company>
 <jobtitle>Manager</jobtitle>
 <phone1>0161 123 1234</phone1>
 <phone2>07912 123 456</phone2>
 <fax>0161 123 1235</fax>
 <email>john@abc.com</email>
 <address>1 High Street</address>
 <address2>This Village</address2>
 <towncity>This Town</towncity>
 <postcode>BB12 6EG</postcode>
 <dobday>01</dobday>
 <dobmonth>01</dobmonth>
 <dobyear>1990</dobyear><
 <contacttime>Anytime</contacttime>
 <data1>Ford</data1>
 <data2>Mondeo</data2>
 <data3>2005</data3>
 <data4>4000</data4>
 </lead>
</data>
```

Now, is it possible to do this as a Guzzle post request? I have stored the XML as a string and tried to pass it through:

```
    $res = $client->request('POST',   
       'http://site.flg360.co.uk/api/APILeadCreateUpdate.php', [
    $xml,

  ]);
  echo($res->getStatusCode());
  die();
```

Which gives a status of 200, no matter what I enter as the XML (The XML could be badly formatted) still gives me a 200 code.

Any ideas to where I am going wrong?

Comment: You know 200 is standard response for successful HTTP requests, even if you send badly formatted xml their api might send you that status code. Aren't there any other info or error codes?

Comment: What is the expected status code? As Atilla said 200 marks a success. Have you tried getting the response body?

Comment: @Andreas - Getting "<message>No input was received.</message>\n" ??

Comment: In the array passed to the client try ['body'=>$xml]

Comment: @Andreas Still getting the same. :( Tried with body, but nothing. There is very little documentation and very little examples

Comment: I am guessing you are using the latest version of Guzzle right ?

Comment: @Andreas Yes. I am now using the string (Before, I was trying with `SimpleXMLElement`) but now, with the string, I get: The input could not be parsed. meaning that the API got something, but it wasn't formatted correctly

Comment: From your question that was not obvious (that your where using a SimpleXMLElement), the raw data should be there. So now i guess it's a matter of formatting the xml string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107967/discussion-between-phorce-and-andreas).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's an issue with the XML string you are trying to send. 2 errors make the XML invalid.

There are currently 2 errors. One in the closing key tag. There is an extra < character. And the second error is at the closing dobyear tag. There is an extra < character after it.

Hope that helped.